# Schengen visa through VFS in India: No update for 20 days

Tags: schengen-visas, france, application-status, vfs-global, student-visas

I applied for a Student short-stay visa (France) through VFS in Delhi, India on 5 April 2022. I received an update on 6 April, saying, "Your Visa application Ref no. [redacted] has been Forwarded to the Embassy/Consulate on 06/04/2022"

That was the last update I received and since then, no updates. It has now been more than 20 calendar days (14 business days). Should I be worried? Whom should I contact?

**Update:**
On 28 April, the embassy sent me an email asking me to send them (via email) a letter explaining my field of research. I sent it on the same day (after working hours). But even after that my visa hasn't been approved yet. It has been 37 calendar days since my appointment.

I'm supposed to leave on 21 May. Only 6 working days are left before that. I don't think there's anything I can do except wait, and update this post while I'm waiting.

Comment: Have you tried contacting VFS?

Comment: @Traveller I did contact VFS. They just said my passport is currently with the embassy, and gave no additional information.

Answer (score 4):

VFS is notorious for its delays and you should not be surprised at all unless a shorter turnaround time was promised to you in writing. You can contact VFS but it sounds like your best bet is to simply continue patiently waiting for updates.